# Map or table of libuv converstions to ANSI?

Tags: node.js, libuv

I am trying to fix an implementation of readline for the browser, and it would be nice if I could have the same behaviour that libuv for windows does. I want to know where can I find which keycodes maps to what?
For example from https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/HEAD/lib/internal/readline/utils.js#L232
we know that

```js
fkeymap={
    f1:'[[A',
    f2:'[[B',
    f3:'[[C',
    f4:'[[D',
    f5:'[[E'
}
```

We can test ourselves this if we run this code in node

```js
var readline = require('readline'),
    rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);
process.stdin.on('keypress', function(s, key) {
  console.log("keypress event",{s,key})
});
```

but if you start combining <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd> codes, you start getting wild ansi combinations, for example <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f9</kbd> maps to `"\x1b[33^"` is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find this table documented anywhere, but I am going to post the data that I got by experimentally trying all the keys in my keyboard available, hope this helps someone. I prefix the keys with 'c' to mean that control was pressed, and 's' to mean that shift was pressed.

```
keys={
f1:"[[A",
f2:"[[B",
f3:"[[C",
f4:"[[D",
f5:"[[E",
f6:"[17~",
f7:"[18~",
f8:"[19~",
f9:"[20~",
f10:"[21~",
f11:"[23~",
f12:"[24~",
cf1:"[11^",
cf2:"[12^",
cf3:"[13^",
cf4:"[14^",
cf5:"[15^",
cf6:"[17^",
cf7:"[18^",
cf8:"[19^",
cf9:"[20^",
cf10:"[21^",
cf11:"[23^",
cf12:"[24^",
sf1:"[23~",
sf2:"[24~",
sf3:"[25~",
sf4:"[26~",
sf5:"[28~",
sf6:"[29~",
sf7:"[31~",
sf8:"[32~",
sf9:"[33~",
sf10:"[34~",
sf11:"[23$",
sf12:"[24$",
csf1:"[23^",
csf2:"[24^",
csf3:"[25^",
csf4:"[26^",
csf5:"[28^",
csf6:"[29^",
csf7:"[31^",
csf8:"[32^",
csf9:"[33^",
csf10:"[34^",
csf11:"[23@",
csf12:"[24@",
home:"[1~",
insert:"[2~",
delete:"[3~",
end:"[4~",
pageup:"[5~",
pagedown:"[6~",
chome:"[1;5~",
cinsert:"[2;5~",
cdelete:"[3;5~",
cend:"[4;5~",
cpageup:"[5;5~",
cpagedown:"[6;5~",
shome:"[1;2~",
sinsert:"[2;2~",
sdelete:"[3;2~",
send:"[4;2~",
spageup:"[5;2~",
spagedown:"[6;2~",
cshome:"[1;6~",
csinsert:"[2;6~",
csdelete:"[3;6~",
csend:"[4;6~",
cspageup:"[5;6~",
cspagedown:"[6;6~"
}
```

Comment: This does not look completely correct, when there is same value for `f11` and `sf1` (`"[23~"`).

Comment: Anyway.. I really wonder, who invented this mess and if there is some logic behind it:/